# MVC4 Bundling (Based on Device Type)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

So looking at the bundleconfig.cs it should permit to bundle based on device type. Only prob is since it is in App_Start it doesn't allow me to access the Request object. Any ideas how to make device based bundling possible?

Comment: Great question. We sure don't want to be sending unnecessary JavaScript and image files to mobile devices.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously you can't access a request in `App_Start`, since no request is being made to your app at that point. `BundleConfig.cs` only declares which bundles are *available*, you should select the correct one in your views.

You can look at the example code from [this MVC 4 tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features):

#### BundleMobileConfig.cs

```cs
public class BundleMobileConfig {
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles) {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquerymobile").
            Include("~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Mobile/css").
            Include("~/Content/Site.Mobile.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/jquerymobile/css").
            Include("~/Content/jquery.mobile-{version}.css"));
    }
}
```

#### _Layout.Mobile.cshtml

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/Mobile/css", "~/Content/jquerymobile/css")    
</head>
<!-- etc -->
```

Comment: This is exactly right. Also note that the article describes how to be more specific than mobile/non-mobile in the section labeled Browser-Specific Views. You link a string (aka display mode) to some browser agent detection logic like: "iPhone" when browser agent string contains "iPhone". Then you can create _Layout.iPhone.cshtml

Comment: I don't think this includes the jQuery Mobile .js file on _Layout.Mobile.cshtml.

Comment: @DOK It does not. It's not really what the OP's question is about, which is how to serve some bundles on a per-device basis, not how to set up jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Create bundles for all devices you want to support in `BundleConfig`. Then, in your view, use the appropriate bundle based on the device derived from `Request.Browser`.